# MessagingException: Error encountered while executing mapping - Where to see response message?

Tags: web-services, soap, sap-pi

I'm running an SAP PI/PO scenario and having a problem with finding the response message (the error one).

Scenario:
***PROXY (class) -> SAP PI/PO 7.5 -> SOAP (wsdl)***

The error when executing the scenario is:

> Transmitting the message using connection
> SOAP_http://sap.com/xi/XI/System failed, due to:
> com.sap.engine.interfaces.messaging.api.exception.MessagingException:
> Error encountered while executing mapping:
> com.sap.aii.af.service.mapping.MappingException:
> com.sap.aii.utilxi.misc.api.ResourceException: Could not determine
> mapping steps for message 3b14b3f8-0860-11ed-a034-000001795062

The problem is that I cannot find the message (3b14b3f8-0860-11ed-a034-000001795062) in SAP PI monitor. It's the response message (who is causing the error), as the request message I did find in the monitor and it's correct.

[image: SAP PI Monitor]

Where I can find it? Why is not showing?

From what I read, this problem happens with several reasons, I just want to find this message.

The webservice works correctly, I test it in SOAP UI.

Comment: it's not the response message, it is the mapping process itself, which is causing the error. Try to select the request message and press "related messages"

Comment: Hi, @Suncatcher, Thanks for your reply. The problem, as you say, is about the mapping process in the response message. I did try to see "related messages," but I couldn't find the messages. The actual concern is that to see the messages, I had to activate the logging in the "Integrated Configuration" (Integration Builder). Then, I searched for the "related messages" and found the response error, which PI couldn't apply the mapping (it was something related to the "Soap Action"). Thank you.

Comment: so post that exact SOAP Action error here

Answer (score 0):

To find the response message (which contains the error), we have to first activate the Integrated Configuration log (it's not active by default).

To activate the log, we have to follow these steps (more info: https://blogs.sap.com/2012/11/06/message-staging-and-logging-options-in-advanced-adapter-engine-of-pi-73x/)

1. Go to "Advanced Settings" in the target Integrated Configuration.
2. Change the "Use global configuration" radio button to "Use scenario-specific configuration" in both, "Staging" and "Loging".
3. Change all "Staging" lists to "Store".
4. Change all "Logging" lists to "Log".
5. Save and activate.

Now, in the SAP PO monitor (Message monitor), by clicking the "Related Messages" option, we can see the response message error.

[image: Related Messages]

[image: Error content]

In this case, the error was:

> <sap:Error xmlns:sap='http://sap.com/xi/XI/Message/30'
> SOAP:mustUnderstand='1'>sap:CategoryXIAdapter</sap:Category><sap:Code
> area='SOAP'>FAULT</sap:Code>sap:P1http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none</sap:P1>sap:P2ActionNotSupported</sap:P2>sap:AdditionalTextThe
> message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a
> ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because
> of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and
> receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the
> receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and
> the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message,
> Transport, None).</sap:AdditionalText><sap:ApplicationFaultMessage
> namespace='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none'>ActionNotSupported</sap:ApplicationFaultMessage></sap:Error>

In which the Action was empty.